# Laravel many to many Relationship, is there a way to generate automatically pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I there possibly a way to have Laravel genrating automatically the table containing pivot indexes on a ManytoMany Relationship. Or maybe via artisan?

Until now I'm creating my Entity models (e.g. User and Role: a user has many roles and a roles is assumed by many user)
 I define the belongsToMany method in each model.

Then I create migrations for create_users_table, create_roles_table, and create_role_user_table)

It would be great if there's a command that after creating the two Entities creates the third with n:n relationships table.

(Maybe the answer is goin to be : no it does not exists...)

Comment: I don't think it can be done automatically, just it's easy to create yourself?

Comment: Yes I suppose so.. but if ever there's the chance, or it's provided functionality why not using it? just arguing...

Comment: Fair enough. No harm in checking I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using [Laravel 5 Generators Extended package](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended):

`php artisan make:migration:pivot User Role`

Install the package and then you will can use this and more new commands. Run `php artisan` after installing the package to see all the commands you can use.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about that

Comment: I felt like there was a way... :) Thx!